# What does it mean whe you have: case state is when vale1 => state <= value2 in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

This line of code gets me confused. I don't get how it works, I know `=>` and `<=` are assigning symbols, but why 2 assignments to the same thing?

Comment: No, `=>` is not an 'assigning symbol' (assignment is signified by `<=` for signal objects while variable assignment or initial value is indicated by `:=`).

Comment: Oh :). Thnx, so what does => mean?

Comment: How do I like your comment, because that was a nice ecplanation

Comment: This is the original code btw:  (case SEL is
  when "01" =>   Z <= A;)

Comment: Nvm you answered my question, please put it as an answer so I can choose it as best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David points out, `=>` is not an assignment symbol.

It's a mapping symbol, or an association. Its use is consistent throughout VHDL - it's always used to associate something (often a name) with something else (often a value).

Here, within a case statement, it's used to associate a case choice `when vale1` with the correct action for that state, which can be any valid sequence of statements. In this case, `state <= value2;`

You may find it clearer to write

```
case state is
   when vale1 =>
      state <= value2;
   when ...
      ...
   when others =>
      state <= idle;
end case;
```

which makes the logical structure clearer than trying to do too much in a line.

Other places you'll see it are in parameter lists. Given a function with several parameters (some of which are optional) you may have seen errors creep into programs in other languages where values get associated with the wrong parameters...

```
setPixelColour (100, 50, 17, 0.5);   -- not obvious, prone to mistakes
```

You can make it clearer what's going on, and avoid mistakes by associating each parameter with its name :

```
setPixelColour ( x => 100, 
                 y => 50, 
                 alpha => 17, 
                 opacity => 0.5);   -- obvious what you're trying to do
```

The same is true of port maps, where you are connecting signals up to the ports of a component.

As David says, another use is in creating aggregates, such as records or arrays.

If you define an Employee record, you might then declare

```
Boss : Employee := (Name => "Richard Branson", Job => CEO, Salary => 999000);
```

Or you might create an array using an aggregate:

```
type Month is (Jan, Feb, Mar, ... Dec);   -- we'll index the array with an enumeration
Days : array (Month range Jan to Dec) of Natural := (
   Feb => 28,
   Apr => 30,
   Jun => 30,
   Sep => 30,
   Nov => 30,
   others => 31);
```

Comment: Also in aggregate expressions.  `=>` is used in *formal* association (as opposed to *positional* association.

Comment: Thanks guys. And cuz I'm a noob at this website, I don't even know how to mark it as best, and I can't vote up because I require 15 reputation. BUT THANKS, tall really did answer my question!